# Did react change serviceEorker.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

I noticed reportWebVitals().Is this an update from React which got rid of serviceWorker.js and replaced it with reportWebVitals.js?

Comment: Yes, latest create-react-app does not include the basic serviceWorker setup as before

Comment: [Yes](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app). If you want that file, try `npx create-react-app my-app --template pwa`. Otherwise you'll have to create it yourself.